# Sainsmart Usb relay control

Tags: c#

I have Purchased a [SainSmart 16 Channel controller USB HID Programmable Control Relay Module](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-16-channel-controller-usb-hid-programmable-control-relay-module.html) to control the corresponding 16 channel relay board.

The source code provided is quite terrible, but included was an cmd line program that works quite well to control the relays. I'm trying to make a GUI using C# to send commands to the program. I Did a bit of reading on this site, but I didn't get too far.

Ultimately I need to send the argument "afEd5 open 01" to CommandApp.exe then pause for a few milliseconds then send argument "afEd5 close 01".

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE: Figured out most of the coding thus far, only small issue I have now is the location of the CommandApp.exe. I'd prefer it was located with the the primary exe of the application rather than in the root of C.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GenesisDigitalInterface
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    // Toggle Power Button relay
    private void PowerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process controlusb = new Process();
        controlusb.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\CommandApp.exe");
        controlusb.StartInfo.Arguments = "afEd5 open 01";
        controlusb.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        controlusb.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
        controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        controlusb.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        controlusb.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\CommandApp.exe");
        controlusb.StartInfo.Arguments = "afEd5 close 01";
        controlusb.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        controlusb.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
        controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        controlusb.Start();
    }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If only the CommandApp.exe program didn't reset the board (turn off all relays) when issuing new commands. Or have you figured out how to close two or more relays at the same time?

Comment: try this : https://github.com/gigacycle/USB-Relay-Manager-HID-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you initialized  `ProcessStartInfo` wrong. It takes the program name as argument but I don't know what you passed so I guess you should pass `"C:\\CommandApp.exe"` and you should pass `"afEd5 open 01"` as its argument, then start the process.

So the code should look like this:

```
Process controlusb = new Process();
controlusb.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\CommandApp.exe");
controlusb.StartInfo.Arguments = "afEd5 open 01";
controlusb.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
controlusb.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
controlusb.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to use this particular board in a test fixture we are developing. The documentation consists of a hex value table with no descriptions or examples. The byte packet is 17 bytes in length and has address, on/off commands and some reverse address check byte. The rest of the bytes are "fixed" for single turn-on and turn off. I have put together a single windows app in C# that operates each individual relay. (One at a time. I never got the all-ON and all-OFF to work.) I will include the code here, but I wish I could attach the whole solution.

Things to note:

1. Relay On command is: hex = 0x46,0x46 (yeah, two bytes of the same thing.
2. Relay Off command is: hex = 0x30, 0x30
3. There needs to be an address translation to get the right Relay. I.e. Relay #1 = 0x30, Relay #2 is 0x31, etc... I put the values into a static byte array, and use the relay integer description, 1,2,etc.. as the index to return the hex address. I think it makes it easier that way.
4. I update the two bytes for On/Off as needed in the TX string.(Along with the address.)
5. ***Special Note: the "extra" control byte (why???) is not the same for both turn-on and turn-off. In my code, I built two byte strings. One handles the control byte for turn-on and the other for Turn-off.
6. Note: this program has a return data buffer (Rxbuffer) I was expecting some kind of acknowledgement or at least a command echo, but nothing is returned from the Relay board.

Other than all that, it seems to work. Good luck!

[16 Channel Test UI Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDppv.jpg)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

// 16ChannelTest.cs  v1.0
// Program to test C# operation of Sain SMART 16 Channel Serial Relay Board
// 7/1/2021 - mwille
// Program "assumes" Com4 is the Serial Relay Board. - Will post an error msg in the textbox if it can't find Com4.
// Developed to support testing and calibration of controller boards.
//

namespace _16ChannelTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
                       
        static byte[] TXbuffer = new byte[17] {0x3A,0x46,0x45,0x30,0x35,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x46,0x46,0x30,0x30,0x46,0x45,0x0D,0x0A};
        static byte[] Convert_Address = new byte[17] { 0x00,0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46 };
        static byte[] T_On_Chk_Value = new byte[17] { 0x00,0x45, 0x44, 0x43, 0x42, 0x41, 0x39, 0x38, 0x37, 0x36, 0x35, 0x34, 0x33, 0x32, 0x31, 0x30, 0x46 };
        static byte[] T_Off_Chk_Value = new byte[17] { 0x00, 0x44, 0x43, 0x42, 0x41, 0x39, 0x38, 0x37, 0x36, 0x35, 0x34, 0x33, 0x32, 0x31, 0x30, 0x46, 0x45 };
        static byte[] RXbuffer = new byte[18];
        static int Relay_Number = 1;
        
        private void btn_Start_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM4";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;

            try
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                tb_Logging.AppendText("Exception Thrown \r\n");
                tb_Logging.AppendText("" + exc);
                tb_Logging.AppendText("\r\n");
            }

            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {              
                tb_Logging.AppendText("Data Logging Started...");
                tb_Logging.AppendText("\r\n");
            }
        }

        public void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.BytesToRead == 17)
                serialPort1.Read(RXbuffer, 0, 17);

            /* Return to UI thread */
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

            serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
        }

        private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tb_Logging.AppendText("--> ");
            tb_Logging.AppendText(BitConverter.ToString(RXbuffer));
            tb_Logging.AppendText("\r\n");
        }

        private void clear_RX_Buffer()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
            {
                RXbuffer[i] = 0x00;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                serialPort1.Close();
        }

        private void Send_Relay_Cmd(byte Relay_ID, byte RCmd, byte Check)     // Relay_ID = 1->16, RCmd = 0x46 to turn-on, 0x30 to turn-off, Check = manufacturer set value??? 
        {
            // If the port is closed, don't try to send a character.
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen) return;

            serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();

            // If the port is Open, setup byte[] array with appropriate elements.

            // First, assign hex address using numeric pointer.           
            TXbuffer[8] = Relay_ID;     //Relay Address

            TXbuffer[9] = RCmd;     // Control Byte #1 - 
            TXbuffer[10] = RCmd;    // Control Byte #2 - 0x46 to turn-on, 0x30 to turn-off            

            TXbuffer[14] = Check;    //Some kind of reverse order check???
            
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            // Send the TXbuffer
            serialPort1.Write(TXbuffer, 0, 17);

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            write_Text();
        }
                
        private void write_Text()
        {
            tb_Logging.AppendText("<-- ");
            tb_Logging.AppendText(BitConverter.ToString(TXbuffer));
            tb_Logging.AppendText("\r\n");
        }

        // This is the Turn-On button function. It performs the majority of byte formatting for the TX function.
        private void Btn_T_On_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte Relay_Address;
            byte Relay_Cmd;
            byte Relay_Check_Byte;

            // Using the integer number as the index, return the manufacturers specific hex address byte.
            Relay_Address = Convert_Address[Relay_Number];

            // Since this is the "Turn-On" button, set the command 
            Relay_Cmd = 0x46;

            // Using the integer number as the index, return the manufacturers specific hex check byte.
            Relay_Check_Byte = T_On_Chk_Value[Relay_Number];

            Send_Relay_Cmd(Relay_Address,Relay_Cmd,Relay_Check_Byte);
        }

        private void Btn_T_Off_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte Relay_Address;
            byte Relay_Cmd;
            byte Relay_Check_Byte;

            // Using the integer number as the index, return the manufacturers specific hex address byte.
            Relay_Address = Convert_Address[Relay_Number];

            // Since this is the "Turn-On" button, set the command 
            Relay_Cmd = 0x30;

            // Using the integer number as the index, return the manufacturers specific hex check byte.
            Relay_Check_Byte = T_Off_Chk_Value[Relay_Number];

            Send_Relay_Cmd(Relay_Address, Relay_Cmd, Relay_Check_Byte);
        }
                
        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 1;
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 2;
        }

        private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 3;
        }

        private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 4;
        }

        private void radioButton5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 5;
        }

        private void radioButton6_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 6;
        }

        private void radioButton7_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 7;
        }

        private void radioButton8_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 8;
        }

        private void radioButton9_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 9;
        }

        private void radioButton10_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 10;
        }

        private void radioButton11_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 11;
        }

        private void radioButton12_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 12;
        }

        private void radioButton13_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 13;
        }

        private void radioButton14_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 14;
        }

        private void radioButton15_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 15;
        }

        private void radioButton16_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Relay_Number = 16;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this board has an FTDI chip, right? Then you can just open the COM port and send 3 bytes as follows:

0xFF, Relay #, 0x00(disable) or 0x01(enable)

0xFF is the header

You can also send just ONE byte 0x00 for All Off or 0xFF for All On

In python you could do this:

```
serial_port.write(bytearray([0xFF, channel, off_on]))
```

The only thing I could not figure out yet is how to get just the status. I see that the program "8 Relay Board Manager 1.4" is able to get the status but I don't know how. I used the Serial Monitor to watch the communication and no activity at all. My suspicion is that they are using the USB approach instead of the serial port.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use this code from https://github.com/ondrej1024/crelay/files/194375/sain-usb-hid.c.txt, but it did not work for me. I'd previously tried many other solutions, but they did not work for me, either.

So, I've written my own code for SainSmart 16-Channel Controller USB HID Programmable Control Relay (a console app to replace CommandApp.exe). You can use this.

The code looks like:

```
Process controlusb = new Process();
controlusb.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\sain-usb-hid-relay-16.exe");
controlusb.StartInfo.Arguments = "1 1";
controlusb.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
controlusb.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
controlusb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
controlusb.Start();
```

Usage: sain-usb-hid-relay-16.exe Param1 Param2

Param1:

```
T or t  - Test of relays from 1 to 16 by ON and OFF. Use Param2 as delay in msec.
A or a  - All relays.
1..16   - Relay number.
```

Param2:

```
1 or 0  - 1 = Relay to ON, 0 = Relay to OFF.
```

Examples:

```
Example: sain-usb-hid-relay-16.exe 5 1
     - Relay #5 is ON.
Example: sain-usb-hid-relay-16.exe 10 0
     - Relay #10 is OFF.
Example: sain-usb-hid-relay-16.exe a 1
     - All relays is ON.
Example: sain-usb-hid-relay-16.exe t 3000
     - All relays will test ON and OFF with each delay = 3000 msec.

sain-usb-hid-relay-16.exe a 1
Relay 65535 ON

sain-usb-hid-relay-16.exe a 0
Relay 65535 OFF

Where 65535 = All relays.
```

You can use it in other apps, execute app as like "sain-usb-hid-relay-16.exe a 1>result.txt"
Then You can read file "result.txt" to parse the result.